# Актуально на текущий момент использовать jQuery Mobile?

Tags: кроссбраузерность, кроссплатформенность, jquery-mobile

Насколько мне известно, эта версия jQuery улучшает кроссплатформенность на стороне мобильных устройств. На данный момент, я не знаю никаких проблем (кроме нескольких нюансов, таких как получение keycode в событиях), которые телефонные браузеры не могли тоже делать, что и обычные браузеры. Если я не прав, поправьте. Вопрос, есть ли необходимость использовать jQuery Mobile на текущий день. И если да, то в каких моментах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть интересные эффекты, но особой значимости на данный момент нет. [Тут можно увидить примеры JQM](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/)